# How to get Data XML or property value From My Api Reponse using wsld?

Tags: java, wsdl

I am using wsdl webservice. I have generated code here. I have want to get xml key value directly from myClass. Here i want get **out_BIN_Data,out_Status & out_XML_Data** properties value.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ApiResponse", namespace = "http://response.api", propOrder = {
"outBINData",
"outStatus",
"outXMLData"
 })
public class ApiResponse {

@XmlElement(name = "out_BIN_Data", required = true, nillable = true)
protected String outBINData;
@XmlElement(name = "out_Status", required = true, nillable = true)
protected String outStatus;
@XmlElement(name = "out_XML_Data", required = true, nillable = true)
protected String outXMLData;

}
```

Please help me

Comment: what do you mean by getting values? when you got the response you could called get getter to get the value

Comment: @MohammadReza Alagheband getter value return null

Comment: How are you passing values to ApiResponse? Do you mean you are calling the soap service that takes ApiResponse as parameter and when you call apiRespinseInstance.outBINData then you are getting null value?

Can you please share client/server code?